# PDO parameterized query code review, how safe am i?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a PHP newbie that just starts to code. Before coding any further, I need to know if I already on the right path on making a secure web. So please review my code samples below.

PHP Version 5.4.34

Database Server version: 5.5.40-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

on connection.php

```
//should I use utf8mb4 and set server connection collation to utf8mb4_general_ci?
//also on html, is including <meta charset="utf-8"> necessary?
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); // enabled by default?
```

select query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbname WHERE username = :username";
$params = array(':username' => $_POST['username']);
    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die();
    }
```

insert query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO log (
    username,
    email, 
    ip,
    time
    ) VALUES (
    :username,
    :email,
    :lastip,
    :lastlog
    )";

$params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':lastip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    ':lastlog' => time()    
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die();      
    }
```

update query

```
$params = array(
   ':username' => $_SESSION['userdata']['username'],
   ':email' => $_POST['email'],
   ':age' => $_POST['age'],
   ':gender' => $_POST['gender']
   );

$query = "UPDATE users SET 
       email = :email,
       age = :age,
       gender = :gender
       where username = :username";
try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($params);          
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die();
    }
```

How safe am i from SQL injection? Safe enough from 2nd order attack?

Comment: If you want someone to review your code you should ask on [codereview.se]. Check their help centre before you post.

Answer (score 0):

Totally safe. The PDO Statement prepares the query to avoid SQL injections. Even if they try, the `prepare()` function make the necessary changes before send to the database.